# MDX to calculate Start of month values across individual dates

Tags: date, ssas, mdx

I am dealing with a requirement as below, the solution i have is either not addressing the complete problem or is extremely slow and in many cases just not feasible. Need a little help on the same.

Problem: Need a query which displays a bunch of measures with cross join of 4 dimension (10 levels) and a date dimension, i need to determine a measures's first available value across time periods such as Start of month, start of year Etc..

I have

- dimA - Level A1
- dimB - Leve B1,B2,B3
- dimC - Level C1
- dimD - Level D1,D2,D3,D4,D5
- Date Dimension - Date, Month, Year as levels.
- Measure - M1 To M5

Query:

```
SELECT 
   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[M1],
              [Measures].[M2],
              [Measures].[M3],
              [Measures].[M4],
              [Measures].[M5],
              [Measures].[M1SOM]} ON COLUMNS
  ,NON EMPTY 
            {
    [DimA].[A1].[A1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B1].[B1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B2].[B2].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B3].[B3].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B4].[B4].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B5].[B5].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMC].[C1].[C1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D1].[D1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D2].[D2].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D3].[D3].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Date].[Month].[Month].ALLMEMBERS*
} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

***The above query has all those cross joins as this query would power an SSRS report dataset.

I Need to create a new calculated measure or a real (persisted measure) that displays the Start of month & Start of year Values. Below are the options i have currently. Lets assume, Measure M1 is the one for which i need the SOM and SOY values.

1. **Create a persisted measure** (M1SOM) based off the measure M1 and provide an aggregation function of "FirstNonEmpty" : This works perfectly when we run a query at Month level i.e. in the above query have [Date].[Month].[Month].Allmembers instead of [Date].[Date].[Date].Allmembers. It displays the first available non empty value of the month. However, this means the rest of the measures are aggregated at month level. If i want to display the daily values of the other measures along with SOM values for this measure it wont work, cause the scope now changes to a single date and i just get the daily value in the M1SOM measure as well.
2. **Create a calculated measure** (M1SOM) as below, along with the query above and the same thing happens. Cant display the SOM values at a daily date level.

   `WITH MEMBER [Measures].[M1SOM] AS ([Date].[Date].FirstChild,[Measures].[M1])`
3. **Create a calculated member** as below, *This works!* however, the **query absolutely kills my** machine and **takes forever to execute**, if i run it with more than 3 levels in the cross join.

   `WITH MEMBER M1SOM AS Head(NonEmpty({[Date].[Date].Parent.Children}*[Measures].[M1SOM])).Item(0)`

Is there a better way to achieve the SOM and SOY calculations at a daily level?

Thanks

Srikanth

Answer (score 0):

(this is untested)

Does this return the first date of the month:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[FirstDayOfMonth] AS 
    OpeningPeriod(
      [Date].[Date].[Date],
      [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT
    ).MemberValue 
SELECT 
   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[M1],
              [Measures].[M2],
              [Measures].[M3],
              [Measures].[M4],
              [Measures].[M5],
              [Measures].[FirstDayOfMonth] } ON COLUMNS
  ,NON EMPTY 
            {
    [DimA].[A1].[A1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B1].[B1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B2].[B2].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B3].[B3].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B4].[B4].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B5].[B5].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMC].[C1].[C1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D1].[D1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D2].[D2].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D3].[D3].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Date].[Month].[Month].ALLMEMBERS*
} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

(Again untested)

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[FirstDayOfMonthM1] AS 
    (
      OpeningPeriod(
        [Date].[Date].[Date],
        [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT
      ),
    [Measures].[M1]
    )
SELECT 
   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[M1],
              [Measures].[M2],
              [Measures].[M3],
              [Measures].[M4],
              [Measures].[M5],
              [Measures].[FirstDayOfMonthM1] } ON COLUMNS
  ,NON EMPTY 
            {
    [DimA].[A1].[A1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B1].[B1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B2].[B2].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B3].[B3].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B4].[B4].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMB].[B5].[B5].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMC].[C1].[C1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D1].[D1].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D2].[D2].ALLMEMBERS*
    [DIMD].[D3].[D3].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Date].[Month].[Month].ALLMEMBERS*
} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

This seems to be quite a nice reference for playing with time periods:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2877/sql-server-analysis-serviceslead-lag-openingperiod-closingperiod-time-related-functions/

Comment: Yes it does. Having only OpeningPeriod([Date].[Date].[Date]).Name also does the trick.

Comment: How is the efficiency? Does it still kill your machine?

Comment: Good news - glad I could help - `MDX` is a really nice language.

Comment: Umm.. May be my question wasn't clear, but getting the first child in a time dimension doesn't address the issue. The problem is that the query needs to Display the first Non empty Measure value at the designated Time window. for Eg. It would have to display the current days measure value along side the Start of month value ( non empty value). Querying the measure at the first child of the timedimension would return null if there was no value on the first day of the month. Please let me know if this explanation was clear.

Comment: Thanks for the response, This response returns the value against the first available date in a month.However we still run into the issue that if there were no values reported for the first day this query would return null, whereas the requirement was to display the first nonempty value. I.e. in the month of april if there was no measure value for April 1st but was present for 3rd this query would return null and we would like the value for the 3rd to appear as the Start of month value.

Answer (score 0):

So i had posted the same question on Msft forum and have received the below answer. Its a work around suggested by them to address the performance issues. But if anyone doesn't have all the cross joins to slow them down please use one of the three options i listed in my question.

[Like to MSFT answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f870232b-9d10-40c4-8e75-22e437694da6/mdx-for-start-of-month-values-at-daily-level?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

Thanks 
Sri

Special thanks for WhyTheq For the patience and trying to address the solution. Appreciate the effort.